# Data retrieved but Table Cell UILabel is empty?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm retrieving entity data from an endpoint with the following code (I've built my app on Drupal's iOS SDK), and I'm trying to display it in my TableView cell.

That said, when I use the following code to display it in my cell, it doesn't seem to want to work (the label just appears empty)? See console data below as well.

**TableViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *messages;
```

**TableViewController.m**

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];

  NSDictionary *entityData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"] forKey:@"uid"];


            [DIOSEntity
             entityGet:entityData
             name:@"entity_message"
             eid:@"uid"
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id response) {

                 self.messages = (NSMutableArray *)response;

                 NSLog(@"This is all of the data from response %@", response); }


             failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSError *err) { NSLog(@"failed to get data"); }
             ];


        }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {


        static NSString *PointsTableIdentifier = @"MyMessagesCell";

        MyMessagesCell *cell = (MyMessagesCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PointsTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyMessagesCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        }

        NSDictionary *receivedMessages = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[cell subjectLine] setText:[receivedMessages objectForKey:@"field_message_body"]];
        NSLog(@"Received message subject are here %@", receivedMessages);
       return cell;

    }
```

**CONSOLE DATA returns as:**

```
2015-11-23 18:26:47.998 [624:153845] This is all of the data from response {
    arguments =     (
    );
    data =     (
    );
    "field_message_body" =     {
        und =         (
                        {
                format = "<null>";
                "safe_value" = "Testing message center";
                value = "Testing message center";
            }
        );
    };
    "field_message_group_ref" =     (
    );
    "field_message_subject" =     {
        und =         (
                        {
                format = "<null>";
                "safe_value" = Testing;
                value = Testing;
            }
        );
    };
```

Comment: Does the self.messages loads correctly the response? after `self.messages = (NSMutableArray *)response;` ?

Comment: As far as I can see it your returned data is a dictionary and not a array.

Comment: it's also not guaranteed that the network response will complete by the time the cell is being loaded with info; the network call is asynchronous. Also, your text (presumably) is further nested in "safe_value",

Comment: @limfinity self.messages is an NSMutableArray, but correct, response is a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a better management of the response data. As @limfinity said, the responseData is a `NSDictinary`, not a `NSMutableArray`.

Also, you should reload the tableview after setting the messages in `self.messages`, so the table gets the new data from the 'new' `self.messages`:

```
[DIOSEntity
 entityGet:entityData
 name:@"entity_message"
 eid:@"uid"
 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id response) {
     self.messages = (NSMutableArray *)response;

     NSLog(@"This is all of the data from response %@", response); }
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
         [self.tableView reloadData];
     });


 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSError *err) { NSLog(@"failed to get data"); }
];
```

**EDIT**

Just to make a simple (but not so correct) change to make this work and don't crash, you should say:

```
self.messages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:(NSDictionary*)response];
```

instead of:

```
self.messages = (NSMutableArray *)response;
```

But I think you should go deeper and make the response be a `NSArray`, not just one `NSDictionary` (multiple NSDictionaries, instead of just one)

Comment: I implement the above, and i get a crash with the following error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15c53e950'

Comment: I assume it's crashing because messages is an NSDictionary?

Comment: @Brittany see the Edit part if that makes it work, at least for that message you are having as a response.

Comment: Implemented your edit, though now I get this error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14a2625f0'

Comment: @Brittany field_message_body is also a NSDictionary. I think you should understand what is being retreived in response before continuing adding code

Answer (score 0):

The tableView finished loading before you got the response. You can log something in
`numberOfRowsInSection:` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method see if it was before `"This is all of the data from response ..."`.

You can call `[self.tableview reloadData]` on main thread to reload the tableview after you get the messages.

Comment: Ohhh. Ok, that said, when I put [self.tableview reloadData] into my viewDidLoad, the label is still empty?

Comment: @Brittany put it after `self.messages = (NSMutableArray *)response;` in success method, you can see @FabKremer 's answer

Comment: When I put it there though, the app crashes with the error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15c53e950'

Comment: You call `[self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` method so the `self.messages` object should be `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`, but now it's `NSDictionary`. So how about use `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSDictionary`,and I can't find out which part of the response data you need

Comment: I was under the impression that it was still an NSMutable array, due to this line: self.messages = (NSMutableArray *)response;. But apparently it's a dictionary - how can I fix this?

Comment: The response data is not a list, you should get the data you want in the dictionary and save them into a new array. For example, use `NSArray *subjects = response[@'field_message_subject'][@"und"]` to get the subject list and use `NSArray *bodies = response[@'field_message_body'][@"und"]`, you can also save them in a single arrary. Sorry my English is too poor to clarify what I want to say, but I really tried.

Comment: Those lines throw me the error: "Array subscript is not an integer".

Answer (score 0):

Based on your console logs:

```
2015-11-23 18:26:47.998 [624:153845] This is all of the data from response {
    arguments =     (
    );
    data =     (
    );
    "field_message_body" =     {//This is not a String!
        und =         (
                        {
                format = "<null>";
                "safe_value" = "Testing message center";
                value = "Testing message center";
            }
        );
    };
```

`[receivedMessages objectForKey:@"field_message_body"]` is not a string but a dictionary.

You need to parse that object a little more:

```
NSString *value = receivedMessages[@"field_message_body"][@"und"][@"value"];
[[cell subjectLine] setText:value];
```

And also don't forget to reload the tableview after you fetch the data.

Comment: This line gives me an error in xcode that says "Array subscript is not an integer" ?